# What is this boolean operation?

Tags: boolean-operations

**a** and **b** - are my bool-variables. **?** - is some unknown operation
Help my to find operation in expression **a ? b** to get following results:

```
0 ? 0 = 1
0 ? 1 = 0
1 ? 0 = 0
1 ? 1 = 1
```

Comment: its a XNOR (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate)

Comment: That's equality, `a == b`.

Comment: Looks like "Please do my homework for me".

Comment: Keith Thompson, in Russia now is end of the day. My brain doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the truth table for XNOR, aka logical equality. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_equality.

Answer (score 2):

This is [XNOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate) boolean operation.